# como usar callback no window.print()

Tags: jquery

Bom criei uma função de impressão em jQuery, ao ser executada ela oculta das div de menu e imprime a pagina. Ela funciona perfeitamente, mas em alguns browser como o IE e o safari do iPhone ela não funciona.

Notei que o erro ocorre por causa da função de exibir o menu novamente após a impressão. Acho que uma forma de resolver isso, é mandar exibir o menu no callback do print. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Segue o código:

```
        /* Função para imprimir */
        function imprimir() {

            // Remove Menu topo
            $(".header").hide();
            $(".sidenav").hide();
            $(".shadow-full").hide();
            $(".relatorio caption").show();
            $('body').css({"padding-top": "0px"});

            // Imprime a página
            window.print();

            // Adiciona Menu topo
            $(".relatorio caption").hide();
            $(".header").show();
            $('body').css({"padding-top": "40px"});
        }
```

Comment: Está imprimindo com as Divs que deviam estar ocultas, isso? Não seria o caso de voltar a exibir apenas após a impressão?

Comment: Sim ela está exibindo na hora de imprimir. Bom tenho que fazer ela voltar após a impressão.

Comment: Tenta utilizar .promise()  - https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Tem como vc postar um exemplo? se der certo já marca sua resposta.

Comment: Em vez de esconder os elementos na hora de imprimir com js, use só css pra mostrar na impressão somente o que deseja.

Comment: como faço isso?

Comment: Veja na resposta se te atende. Acho mais sossegado que usar js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente só com `css`

```css
@media print
{    
    .no-print
    {
        display: none;
    }
  
    .print-only {
  
    display: inline;
    
    }
  
}

@media screen {
.print-only {
display: none;}
  }
```

```html
<div class="no-print">
  Só aparece na tela
  
</div>

<div class="print-only">

  Aparece só na impressão
  
</div>

<div>

  Aparece em ambos os casos
  
</div>

<input type="button" value="imprimir" onclick="window.print();" />
```

Comment: ok da sua forma faz mais sentido mesmo hahahah, vlw

Comment: Já passei por isso! hahaha E também usava sempre js antes de conhecer essa possibilidade em css